# Dancing instead of running

Tags: running, dancing

I'm considering...actually, I already decided that I want yo substitute running with dancing.

Why? Cause it makes life funnier.

Is there any drawback and therefore I should keep running at least a little bit, or is it perfectly fine is if I invest all my time into dance?

I train mostly, to not die young.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an excellent replacement. Dance can be an extremely effective form of cardio and has more benefits than running.

Pros:

- Engages more muscles. Running is very stringent and to the point. It works the muscles that it needs and that's it. Dancing is fluid and ever changing. You'll use everything you have available to use in the process.
- Dancing is more fun. I mean I like (or liked) running and enjoyed doing it, but I'm not going to pretend that dancing is far more interesting.
- Improved coordination and body intelligence. You have to know how to "move" to dance. This is something that needs to be learned and it's a useful skill in many other elements of life.
- It's social (may also be a con depending on the type of person you are). Running can be pretty lonely at times. Even in groups you're pretty much focused internally. In contract, almost all forms of dance requires a partner with direct interaction.

Cons:

- Dancing may not be as significant a workout than running. This is of course dependent on a lot of things. There are a lot of different dance forms and some are way more active than others, and of course learning beginner dance moves will not be as intense.
- Dance has a much higher learning curve. While you have to learn proper running form, it's certainly a lot easier to just "pick up and go" vs. dance which requires a lot of practice.